# Check if a macro was run with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-experience

I have a interactive workbook with 3 step-by-step buttons so the user can generate a report. I want 2nd macro to check if 1st macro was run and if not, warn the user with a Masgbox to run it first.

Is there a way to determine if a macro was run? Maybe putting a Call at the end of the first 2 macros where a public sub add +1 to a 'counter' variable?

For example:

Macro 2 check if counter = 1,
Macro 3 check if counter = 2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try creating a `Public boolMacro1 as Boolean` variable in a standard module. When first macro runs, it makes it `True`. The second macro will firstly check if it is `True`. Do the same with the second macro (`boolMacro2`. The third one will make the two boolean variables `False`, in order to restart the correct working sequence.

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks. The original workbook can't be saved due to a statement I put in Workbook_BeforeSave. I believe they can remain as False by default.

Comment: They will be `False` of the beginning. If you want running the sequence only once, the may remain `True`. It is not easy to understand what you try accomplishing if you do not tell us...

Comment: @FaneDuru just a communication failure. I understand that I must change it to True after finishing a macro. What I meant is that I can leave it as False by default because whenever the Workbook is opened, it will be False, since the original file cannot be saved after being modified. 'Works as Designed'.

Comment: Have you considered using `GetSettings` and `SaveSettings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Run Macros Sequentially

```
Public RunChecker As Long

Sub Macro1()
    Select Case RunChecker
    Case 1
        MsgBox "You already ran Macro1. To continue, run Macro2.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Case 2
        MsgBox "To continue, run Macro3.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    ' Your code, e.g.:
    MsgBox "Running1", vbInformation
    
    RunChecker = 1
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
    Select Case RunChecker
    Case 0
        MsgBox "You need to run Macro1 first.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Case 2
        MsgBox "You already ran Macro2. To continue, run Macro3.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    ' Your code, e.g.:
    MsgBox "Running2", vbInformation
    
    RunChecker = 2
End Sub

Sub Macro3()
    Select Case RunChecker
    Case 0
        MsgBox "You already finished. To start again, run Macro1.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Case 1
        MsgBox "You need to run Macro2 first.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    ' Your code, e.g.:
    MsgBox "Running3", vbInformation
    
    RunChecker = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it in a similar way, using boolean as sugested by other user. But this is what I was looking for.